# Code First Table Migration - N para N usando Fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
[Table("Area_Cursos_Turma")]
public class Turma
{
    public int TurmaID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
}

[Table("Area_Cursos_Aluno")]
public class Aluno
{
    public int AlunoID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }
}
```

Utilizando o `Migration`, ele cria para mim a tabela no banco: `TurmaAluno`, e gostaria que ele criasse `Area_Cursos_TurmaAluno`.

Tentei o seguinte:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>()
    .HasMany(t=>t.Turmas)
    .WithMany(a => a.Alunos)
    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("Turma_TurmaID")
    .MapRightKey("Aluno_AlunoID")
    .ToTable("Area_Cursos_TurmaAluno"));
```

Aparentemente deu certo. Está certo isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está sim. Há uma sintaxe alternativa levemente diferente:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Turmas)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("Turma_TurmaID");
        m.MapRightKey("Aluno_AlunoID");
        m.ToTable("Area_Cursos_TurmaAluno");
    });
```

O problema é que desta forma você não tem como colocar propriedades extras na sua tabela associativa. Neste caso, você teria que modelar a tabela associativa colocando nela as chaves das entidades Aluno e Turma, mais as colunas extras.

Comment: Isso se chama Fluent API?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Exato. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx